# How to use Perl style memory regex matching with Boost library

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use Perl's regex memory features, which puts matched text in () in variables $1, $2...
Does anyone know how I can do this with Boost, maybe Boost saves the matched text in a different location?
The following line of code says that $1 is undefined.

```
 boost::regex ex( aaa(b+)aaa, boost::regex::perl );
 if(boost::regex_search( line ,ex ))
   set_value( $1 ); // Here $1 should contain all the b's matched in the parenthesis
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The feature is called "capturing" if that helps in your research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a separate overload of `boost::regex_search`

In particular you want one where you pass in a `boost::match_results` structure (by reference).  This will be populated with the sub-expressions (and the portion of the input that was matched), as long as the search is successful.

```
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
std::string line = ...; 
boost::regex ex( "aaa(b+)aaa", boost::regex::perl );
 if(boost::regex_search( line ,results, ex ))
   set_value( results[1] );
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
This did the job :)